# How do I make my render(s) a bit brighter (Image below)

Tags: rendering, lighting

I am a beginner to rendering, or Blender for that matter. I would like my renders to be a bit brighter, I have disabled shadows from the world and lights. Any recommendations are welcome!
[image]

Comment: the easiest ways are to change the materials or to increase the lights power

Comment: you can also adjust the output in the compositor with a Brightness / Contrast node or go into the render properties and change the exposure under Color Management

Comment: Turn your lights up!

Comment: @TheLabCat: moonboots already said that....

Comment: @Chris yes, he did.

Comment: This helped me while doing a project in VSE. It'll help you too in the 3D viewport.
https://88k88.blogspot.com/2021/07/did-you-know-that-view-transform-may.html

Answer (score 1):

I try to explain the steps you need to take to use the proposals of moonboots and Gorgious:

***1) change material:***

If you create a new scene, and render it out you will get:

[image]

If you now click on the materials tab

[image]

[image]

and scroll a bit down and change the color and the emission strength like this:

[image]

you will get:

[image]

***2) increase lights***

again...from the default cube scene...

select your light in the outliner...

[image]

click on the light bulb and increase power a little bit to 5000 and you will get:

[image]

[image]

*** 3) Compositor***

again from default scenario...

click on compositor...

[image]

tap on "use nodes"

[image]

add a node with Shift-A:

[image]

[image]

increase brightness and you will get

[image]

***Exposure***

again from default cube scene...

Tab on scene properties

[image]

color management...

[image]

and increase exposure

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in the Shader Editor. Use the Add menu or Shift+A to add the Bright/Contrast node, select the desired values, and place it between the texture and the Principled BSDF node. Voila!

[image: Bright/Contrast node]